# Ошибка при вызове RTRIM после XMLAGG: ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small

Tags: sql, база-данных, xml, oracle

Есть следующий запрос:

```sql
SELECT 
    CASE 
    WHEN ('[Param.3]' = 'SELECTED') THEN (
        SELECT RTRIM(XMLELEMENT("Rowset", XMLAGG(RW.R ORDER BY RW."ID")), ' ' ) AS Orders
        FROM TMTABLE UL, XMLTABLE('Rowsets/Rowset/Row' PASSING UL.TEXT 
            COLUMNS "ID" NUMBER(19) PATH 'ID', R xmltype path '.') AS RW
       WHERE ID BETWEEN '[Param.1]' and '[Param.2]')
    WHEN ('[Param.3]' = 'ALL' ) THEN (
        SELECT RTRIM(XMLELEMENT("Rowset", XMLAGG(RW.R ORDER BY RW."ID")) , ' ' ) AS Orders
        FROM TMTABLE UL, XMLTABLE('Rowsets/Rowset/Row' PASSING UL.TEXT 
            COLUMNS "ID" NUMBER(19) PATH 'ID', R xmltype path '.') AS RW)
    END AS Orders
FROM dual
```

Этот запрос работает, если относительно небольшое количество записей объединяются  функцией `XMLAGG`. Но если колличество таких записей будет больше, то возникает следующая ошибка:

> ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small

Что надо изменить, чтобы запрос заработал?

<sub>Свободный перевод [XMLAGG with RTRIM issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13299843) от участника [@Soham Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1769939/soham-shah)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/13299843

Answer (score 2):

Надо добавить `.getClobVal()` к результату с типом данных `XMLType` до вызова `RTRIM`.

`XMLAGG` отлично справляется с большим колличеством данных. `TRIM` тоже может работать с CLOB. Но если соединить эти функции вместе, то `XMLType` будет неявно  конвертирован в `VARCHAR2`, а не в `CLOB`.

Например:

```sql
create or replace function testfun return clob is
   c clob;
begin
    c := c||lpad ('a', 4000, 'a');
    c := c||lpad ('b', 4000, 'b');
    return c;
end;
/
--работает, вернёт XMLType
select xmlagg (xmlelement("abc", testfun)) from dual;

--работает, вернёт CLOB
select trim (testfun) from dual;

--ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small
select trim (xmlagg (xmlelement ("abc", testfun))) from dual;

--работает
select trim (xmlagg (xmlelement ("abc", testfun)).getClobVal()) from dual;
```

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13302613) от участника [@Jon Heller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409172/jon-heller)</sub>